# Symfony2: Testing entity validation constraints

Tags: symfony

Does anyone have a good way to unit test an entity's validation constraints in Symfony2?

Ideally I want to have access to the Dependency Injection Container within the unit test which would then give me access to the validator service. Once I have the validator service I can run it manually:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($entity);
```

I could extend `WebTestCase` and then create a `client` to get to the container as per the docs however it doesn't feel right. The `WebTestCase` and `client` read in the docs as more of a facility to test **actions** as a whole and therefore it feels broken to use it to unit test an entity.

So, does anyone know how to either a) get the container or b) create the validator inside a unit test?

Comment: I'm not really sure which post to choose as the answer below since I think both are correct. I'll tick my own (if no one objects) since it focuses in on just the validator but Matt's answer allows for the whole DIC which could be useful for some people (and I had mentioned it in the original question).

Comment: Choose any of the two answers, there is no problem :) I'm glad if it can help anyone else and also happy that you did solve your problem :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Ok since this got two votes I guess other people are interested.

I decided to get my shovel out and was pleasantly surprised (so far anyway) that this wasn't at all difficult to pull off.

I remembered that each Symfony2 component can be used in a stand alone mode and therefore that I could create the validator myself.

Looking at the docs at: https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/ValidatorFactory.php

I realised that since there was a ValidatorFactory it was trivial to create a validator (especially for validation done by annotations which I am, although if you look at the docblock on the page I linked above you'll also find ways to validate xml and yml).

First:

```
# Symfony >=2.1
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
# Symfony <2.1
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorFactory;
```

and then:

```
# Symfony >=2.1
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMapping()->getValidator();
# Symfony <2.1
$validator = ValidatorFactory::buildDefault()->getValidator();

$errors = $validator->validate($entity);

$this->assertEquals(0, count($errors));
```

I hope this helps anyone else whose conscience wouldn't allow them to just use WebTestCase ;).

Comment: ValidatorFactory is deprecated in Symfony 2.1. You can replace it with Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMapping()->getValidator() if you are using annotations.

Comment: Thanks for that update, its true that this answer has become out-dated with Symfony2.1 to some extent.

Comment: Not all services are so easily constructable - they might need another services or (possibly processed config variables). IMO better would be use container.

Comment: For Symfony 4.2, just replace the assertion by `$this->assertEquals(0, $errors->count());`

Comment: Same for Symfony 5.1. Use `Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMapping()->getValidator();` otherwise the annotations will not validate.

Answer (score 38):

We end up rolling your own base test case to access the dependency container from within a test case. Here the class in question:

```
<?php

namespace Application\AcmeBundle\Tests;

// This assumes that this class file is located at:
// src/Application/AcmeBundle/Tests/ContainerAwareUnitTestCase.php
// with Symfony 2.0 Standard Edition layout. You may need to change it
// to fit your own file system mapping.
require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../app/AppKernel.php';

class ContainerAwareUnitTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected static $kernel;
    protected static $container;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$kernel = new \AppKernel('dev', true);
        self::$kernel->boot();

        self::$container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
    }

    public function get($serviceId)
    {
        return self::$kernel->getContainer()->get($serviceId);
    }
}
```

With this base class, you can now do this in your test methods to access the validator service:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
```

We decided to go with a static function instead of the class constructor but you could easily change the behavior to instantiate the kernel into the constructor directly instead of relying on the static method `setUpBeforeClass` provided by PHPUnit.

Also, keep in mind that each single test method in you test case won't be isolated fro, each others because the container is shared for the whole test case. Making modification to the container may have impact on you other test method but this should not be the case if you access only the `validator` service. However, this way, the test cases will run faster because you will not need to instantiate and boot a new kernel for each test methods.

For the sake of reference, we find inspiration for this class from this [blog post](http://www.elao.org/developpement/a-la-decouverte-de-symfony-2-tests-unitaires-sur-le-modele-phpunit-et-doctrine-2.html). It is written in French but I prefer to give credit to whom it belongs :)

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Ah fantastic! Thank you for your reply - this popped up by ajax as I was writing mine below, helps if I refresh my page first ;). This looks like a good solution also, especially if you need to access more than just the validator on the container. Also you bring up a good point in my code below whereby the validator could be held as an instance variable instead of being re-created for each test method for performance sake. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Note that booting the whole kernel can be heavy and may slow down your tests considerably. Use with caution.

Comment: For me, the class needs to be declared `abstract`, otherwise PHPUnit thinks it is a test class (even if I move it out of the `Tests` directory and remove `Test` from the name – I assume this is because it extends `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`...)

Comment: @Tim it's probably because of missing/incorrect PHPUnit configuration: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#phpunit-configuration

Comment: **Symfony 3 :** A new class has been created for such tests : the [KernelTestCase](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.html)

Answer (score 28):

I liked Kasheens answer, but it doesn't work for Symfony 2.3 anymore.
There are little changes:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
```

and

```
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->getValidator();
```

If you want to validate Annotations for instance, use enableAnnotationMapping() like below:

```
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->enableAnnotationMapping()->getValidator();
```

the rest stays the same:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($entity);
$this->assertEquals(0, count($errors));
```

Comment: Official usage link https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/master/README.md#usage ; 

    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
    $validator = Validation::createValidator();
    $violations = $validator->validateValue('Bernhard', new Length(array('min' => 10)));

Comment: I really don't know why this is not shown in the official Unit Testing documentation for Symfony Forms! Thank you for pointing out this solution.

Answer (score 7):

With Symfony 2.8, it seems that you can now use the `AbstractConstraintValidatorTest` class this way :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Tests\Constraints\AbstractConstraintValidatorTest;
use AppBundle\Constraints\MyConstraint;
use AppBundle\Constraints\MyConstraintValidator;
use AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

class MyConstraintValidatorTest extends AbstractConstraintValidatorTest
{
    protected function getApiVersion()
    {
        return Validation::API_VERSION_2_5;
    }

    protected function createValidator()
    {
        return new MyConstraintValidator();
    }

    public function testIsValid()
    {
        $this->validator->validate(null, new MyEntity());

        $this->assertNoViolation();
    }

    public function testNotValid()
    {
        $this->assertViolationRaised(new MyEntity(), MyConstraint::SOME_ERROR_NAME);
    }
}
```

You have got a good sample with the [IpValidatorTest class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Tests/Constraints/IpValidatorTest.php)

Comment: Little typo in the first ``use``. Should be ``Tests`` instead of ``Test``

Answer (score 5):

The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41884661/4560833 has to be changed a little for Symfony 4:

Use `ConstraintValidatorTestCase` instead of `AbstractConstraintValidatorTest`.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer (b): Create the Validator inside the Unit Test (Symfony 2.0)

If you built a `Constraint` and a `ConstraintValidator` you don't need any DI container at all.

Say for example you want to test the `Type` constraint from Symfony and it's `TypeValidator`. You can simply do the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\TypeValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Type;

class TypeValidatorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  function testIsValid()
  {
    // The Validator class.
    $v = new TypeValidator();

    // Call the isValid() method directly and pass a 
    // configured Type Constraint object (options
    // are passed in an associative array).

    $this->assertTrue($v->isValid(5, new Type(array('type' => 'integer'))));
    $this->assertFalse($v->isValid(5, new Type(array('type' => 'string'))));
  }
}
```

With this you can check every validator you like with any constraint configuration. You neither need the `ValidatorFactory` nor the Symfony kernel.

> Update: As @psylosss pointed out, this doesn't work in Symfony 2.5. Nor does it work in Symfony >= 2.1. The interface from `ConstraintValidator` got changed: `isValid` was renamed to `validate` and doesn't return a boolean anymore. Now you need an `ExecutionContextInterface` to initialize a `ConstraintValidator` which itself needs at least a `GlobalExecutionContextInterface` and a `TranslatorInterface`... So basically it's not possible anymore without way too much work.

Comment: It results `Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\TypeValidator::isValid()` in symfony 2.5

Comment: @psylosss You're right. Apparently the ConstraintValidator interface got changed from Symfony 2.0 (where this answer originates from) to Symfony 2.1. See [GitHub commit](https://github.com/symfony/Validator/commit/529a58d990ae35e0f7c2d80f12b279fd7ec90709).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the WebTestCase. If you don't want a client, don't create one ;) But using a possibly different service than your actual application will use, that's a potential pit fall. So personally, I've done like this:

```
class ProductServiceTest extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase
{

    /**
     * Setup the kernel.
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = self::getKernelClass();

        self::$kernel = new $kernel('dev', true);
        self::$kernel->boot();
    }

    public function testFoo(){
        $em = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $v  = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('validator');

        // ...
    }

}
```

It's less DRY than Matt answer -- as you'll repeat the code (for each test class) and boot the kernel often (for each test method), but it's self-contained and require no extra dependencies, so it depends on your needs. Plus I got rid of the static require.

Also, you're sure to have the same services that your application is using -- not default or mock, as you boot the kernel in the environnement that you wish to test.

Answer (score 0):

If people still read this one in 2023, prefer to inject the ValidatorInterface for Symfony > 3 / 4.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

// ...

$this->validator->validate($myEntity);
```

Comment: But how do you inject it in a test case class ?

Comment: Using the `getContainer`, you can have it like : `$this->validator = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('validator');` in your `setUp` method

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work with sf6+, validator service is not loaded anymore in test kernel. They say it's part of the container optimisation features... The (exotic) solution is to define a public alias for validator...