# PHPUnit test case aware of symfony2 dependency injection container

Tags: testing, dependency-injection, phpunit, symfony

I'm actually testing a [bundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle) that I created. All the code is fully unit tested but now, I want to test if my symfony2 services can be request without any trouble.

For that, I need the symfony2 dependency injection container in my test case. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why not mocking it. That's the aim of unit testing and dependency injection : isolating the tested code.

Comment: I understand your point of view but my interest in this test is to check that my [services configuration](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.xml) are correctly configured. So, I think mocking it doesn't resolve my issue. (Correct me if I'm wrong :)). Right now, The only solution I imagine is to inject the seymfony 2 dependency injection container in my test and check that calling my services doesn't throw an exception & give me appropriate objects but I don't know how can I do that.

Comment: Testing your configuration ? That sounds strange.

Comment: I think that's not so strange, I'm actually updating a lot of things in the bundle which force me to add or update some services. My tests don't cover this services, so, each times I update something I must check mannualy my services are correctly configured instead of running my test suite...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently asked a question similar to this in that I needed just the validator, however the person who replied to my question first had a solution which gave access to the whole container.

Basically you can pick apart `WebTestCase` in order to see how it builds the Symfony2 environment and make your own base class which is Symfony aware as it were.

Here is the answer, I hope it helps: [Symfony2: Testing entity validation constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004601/symfony2-testing-entity-validation-constraints/7016258#7016258)