# Test access_control in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I want to test that my `access_control` is working as expected, that certain roles don't have access to a page while other roles do.

I can do this using Functional Tests, logging in each user and testing the response from the given page. I don't think this way is very maintainable and was wondering if anybody else had a better way?

I am using a combination of annotations and access_control configuration to prevent access to controllers.

Comment: check this link http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html also this answer seems to have gotten a lot of votes http://stackoverflow.com/a/8479353/2149092