# Access Symfony 2 container via Unit test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

How do I access the Symfony 2 container within a Unit test? My libraries need it so it's essential.

The test classes extend `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` so there is no container.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004601/symfony2-testing-entity-validation-constraints/7016258#7016258

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Support is now built into Symfony. See http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html

Here's what you could do:

```php
namespace AppBundle\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class MyDatabaseTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $container;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
    }
}
```

For a bit more modern and re-usable technique see https://gist.github.com/jakzal/a24467c2e57d835dcb65.

Note that using container in unit tests smells. Generally it means your classes depend on the whole container (whole world) and that is not good. You should rather limit your dependencies and mock them.

Comment: Thanks @Jakub for the answer. And also appreciate your comment about injecting the container. Cheers.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this , in your set up function

```
protected $client;
protected $em;

/**
 * PHP UNIT SETUP FOR MEMORY USAGE
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable) crawler set instance for test.
 */
public function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient(array(
            'environment' => 'test',
    ),
        array(
            'HTTP_HOST' => 'host.tst',
            'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0',
    ));

    static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
    static::$kernel->boot();
    $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
                               ->get('doctrine')
                               ->getManager();
    $crawler = $this->client->followRedirects();
}
```

Don't forget to set your teardown function

```
    protected function tearDown()
{
    $this->em->close();
    unset($this->client, $this->em,);
}
```

Comment: This comment should be selected. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

#### Update 2018: Since Symfony 3.4/4.0 there is a problem with service testing.

It's called "testing private services", possible solutions are [described here](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/05/17/how-to-test-private-services-in-symfony/)

---

For various different configs you also use **[lastzero/test-tools](https://github.com/lastzero/test-tools#service-container) package**.

It sets up a container for you and is ready to use:

```
use TestTools\TestCase\UnitTestCase;

class FooTest extends UnitTestCase
{
    protected $foo;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->foo = $this->get('foo');
    }

    public function testBar()
    {
        $result = $this->foo->bar('Pi', 2);
        $this->assertEquals(3.14, $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/05/17/how-to-test-private-services-in-symfony/

Comment: You may create services_test.yaml files, define aliases for those services you want to access to and make them public

Comment: That is the worst way to spend your programming time, see https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/05/17/how-to-test-private-services-in-symfony/#down-the-smelly-rabbit-hole