# Unit testing a symfony service class with phpunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have a basic class `GenericHelper.php` in directory `Foo/BarBundle/Helper`

I registered it as a service in `Foo/BarBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`:

```
    parameters:
       generic_helper.class: Foo\BarBundle\Helper\GenericHelper

    services:
       generic_helper:
           class: %generic_helper.class%
```

and I'm able to access it in a command by doing the following:

```
    $helper = $this->getContainer()->get('generic_helper');
```

Now, I'd like to unit test that class with PHPUnit; I have the following code (similar to http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html#unit-tests):

```
    namespace Foo\BarBundle\Tests\Helper;

    use Foo\BarBundle\Helper\GenericHelper;

    class GenericHelperTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

        public function testSomeMethod() {
            $helper = new GenericHelper(); //line 10
            $this->assertEquals($helper->someMethod(), SOME_RESULT);
        }
    }
```

Running PHPUnit results in the following error:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Foo\BarBundle\Helper\GenericHelper' not found in /DIR/src/Foo/BarBundle/Tests/Helper/GenericHelperTest.php on line 10
```

Grepping for 'GenericHelper' only yields a few results:

- the Class itself and the Test class
- the services.yml file
- `appDevDebugProjectContainer` files in `app/cache/dev/`, which have all the service getters

**Question(s)**:

- Does Symfony prevent PHPUnit from directly constructing a service class?
- Is there a way to do this without creating a Symfony Container then accessing the service (as done here: [Access Symfony 2 container via Unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972737/access-symfony-2-container-via-unit-test))? I mean, it's still just a basic class...

Comment: It should work, you probably have something wrong with the autoloading of your classes. Could you post your `phpunit.xml` file?

Comment: @Matt I haven't modified the `phpunit.xml.dist` file that came with symfony, but your comment helped me out regardless - running phpunit with `-c app/` (directory with the dist file) worked. I guess it has to do with the specified bootstrap file within? Anyways, thanks!

Comment: Yes because `bootstrap.php.cache` will include the autoloading stuff. You should post an answer to your question and accept it when you will can (I think you must wait something like two days).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running phpunit with the `-c` flag pointing to the directory containing the `phpunit.xml.dist` file solved the issue. Doing this includes `bootstrap.php.cache` and therefore the autoloading stuff necessary.