# Symfony2 getting config params in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I have a Symfony2 service that is constructed using a parameter from config.yml using dependency injection. I'm now trying to unit test it and find that the unit test does not have access to the container and therefore the service. So I should built one myself using mock data. It would make sense to me if I could now read the config parameter (going first to config_test.yml then config.yml etc etc) but it appears that isn't possible either. This appears to make unit testing a service cumbersome as I would need to code the initialisation parameters into the test instead of the config files.

If there really is no way to construct a service with parameters from config.yml during a unit test, does anyone know the logic as to why it is a Bad Thing™?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this post, because I needed config parameters in my tests myself. This was the first hit on Google.

However, this is a solution which works. There might be better ones.

```
<?php

...

require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../../../../app/AppKernel.php");

class MediaImageTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $_application;
    private $storagePath;

    public function setUp() {  
         $kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
         $kernel->boot();
         $this->_application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
         $this->_application->setAutoExit(false)

         $this->storagePath = $this->_application->getKernel()->getContainer()->getParameter('media_path');
    }

    ...
}
```

You might look in to this too: [Access Symfony 2 container via Unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972737/access-symfony-2-container-via-unit-test)
Is a much cleaner solution accessing the kernel within unit tests.

Comment: $container->getParameter() is the answer

Answer (score 15):

This works for me:

```
class MyServiceTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testCookies()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $myParams = $client->getKernel()->getContainer()->getParameter('my_params');
    }
}
```

Comment: although I'm wondering whether there are any issues with extending WebTestCase for unit tests (as it is usually used for functional tests)

Answer (score 4):

Unit testing is about testing a class in isolation from other classes. To unit test your service you shouldn't need to read anything from the configuration. Just pass a value in your test. In the end, it could potentially work with other values, right?

Of course if there's some logic/validation around the accepted values, you should probably cover it by tests. Think how you'd do it if you were taking this value from the configuration. You simply wouldn't be able to test the behaviour with different values.

If you want to verify if your application is working correctly (your classes collaborate the way you expect), use functional tests or an acceptance testing tool (like Behat).

Comment: My service needs to pull in data from our test server (we have servers in production and test modes). What I'm testing here is how the service reacts to the data it gets from there. it's not totally isolated unit testing, but I have already verified that the data coming out of the server is correct and rather than copy and save the server output and feed it in manually to my service, I want to verify that the service can get the data itself.

Comment: So it's not unit testing at all. More an integration or system testing. Simplest thing you could do is to use Symfony's functional tests (which are still PHPUnit tests). Functional test client has an access to the container (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/testing.html#accessing-internal-objects). If you still want to use regular unit test class, look into initialising the container in your unit tests here: https://gist.github.com/1319290

Comment: So how do you do "unit" testing on a class that downloads a file? Would it always be considered functional testing since it reaches outside of itself?

Comment: If the main purpose of the class is the file download, it doesn't reach outside of itself. It would probably use native PHP function to get the file. If your class downloads a file but it's not its main responsibility, it would rely on another class (FileDownloader) which could be mocked in a test and injected into the class under test.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Symfony 3.2.2, but I think that this could work also for you.

It's simply a line:

```
$export_dir = static::$kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('export_dir');
```